# Git repository not exported: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, version-control

Setting up new git installations.

On one Windows laptop, I'm running (under cygwin):

```
git daemon --base-path=/cygdrive/c/work/proj/
```

My project's root is c:\work\proj\proj1.  There is a c:\work\proj\proj1\.git directory.
git-daemon-export-ok exists in c:\work\proj\proj1.  (git-daemon-export-ok can be an empty file, yes?)

On another Windows computer, on the same local network, I've tried many variations of this (under cygwin):

```
git clone git://xx.xx.xx.xx/proj1
```

I expect that the daemon will append 'proj1' to the base-path and do the right thing.

On the server I see:

```
5728] '/cygdrive/c/work/proj/proj1/.git': repository not exported.
```

On the client I see:

```
$ git clone git://xx.xx.xx.xx/proj1
Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/c/work/proj/proj1/.git/  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What am I doing wrong?
TIA...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to create the **git-daemon-export-ok** file in the `.git` directory. Don't commit it into the repository along with your code, but just create an empty file with that name along with the `branches`, `hooks`, `info`, etc. directories.

Comment: Thanks.  The key is putting git-daemon-export-ok in the .git dir, not the parent dir.

Comment: Or use --export-all option to git-daemon

Answer (score 3):

i had this same issue, but for a different reason.  if Ted's answer doesn't work for you, try adding "--enable=receive-pack" to your git-daemon options.  this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gitosis you must add the two following lines in gitosis.conf (note: "repo" != "group") :

```
[repo myrepo]
daemon=yes
```

When you push `gitosis-admin`, it will create `git-daemon-export-ok` automatically.

If you try to create the file manually in the repository instead, it will keep disappearing after some time.

Comment: I though I would add that If the person is using gitolite instead of gitosis then the user can do this automatically by adding `R = daemon` in the sections for the repository that should be clonable with git and the git protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add "--export-all" to get it working for whatever reason