# git-http-backend error

Tags: git, gitstack

I setup git on rodmine. In home everything works fine. I copy all files/server files to my server. Here all web sites works fine. But when I try to use git-http-backend.exe it give me this error in apache log:

```
[Sat May 26 11:31:35 2012] [error] [client 213.81.166.244] 
     Repository not exported: 'D:/XAMPP_Server/gitstack/repositories/project'
```

When I try to browse it chrome it return error 6 ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: trouble with setting up daemon, trouble with git clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112622/git-trouble-with-setting-up-daemon-trouble-with-git-clone)

Comment: If everything else in the configuration is correct, the other question has the right solution.